# Integrating Redux Thunk into async query

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a complete newbie to Redux, and I'm trying to integrate a store which receives data from a successful fetch from the frontend. The data itself is querying Reddit, which I'll then use to display in a simple frontend.

The basic structure of the Redux store is as follows:

[image]

It has four files, each of which contain different bits of code. The code in question is as follows:

**Actions.js**

```
import { ADD_REDDIT } from './actionTypes'

export const addData = (content) => ({
    type: ADD_REDDIT,
    payload: content
})
```

**Actiontypes.js**

```
export const ADD_REDDIT = "ADD_REDDIT"
```

**Selectors.js**

```
export const getRedditState = store => store.redditPosts
```

**Store.js**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { ADD_REDDIT } from './actionTypes'

const initialState = {
    redditPosts: []
}

export const redditReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_REDDIT: {
            const data = action.payload
            return {
                ...state, 
                data
            }
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
    
}

export const store = createStore(redditReducer)
```

The store is then placed as a prop inside of my index.js, within a  component, like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Moving onto my frontend, I have added an async function inside of useEffect, which contains a try/catch block and a fetch within the try block. The fetch returns a jsonResponse, which works as expected up to now.

If the response is ok, I'm then moving it on and calling my 'addData' dispatch, passing in the jsonResponse. I'm then attempting to call the selector to access my state within a console log, but it's returning an empty array (the initial value).

EDIT: Here's my component which is actually calling the useEffect.

```
const Homepage = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const fetchReddit = useSelector(getRedditState)

    useEffect( async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=startups%20")
            if (response.ok) {
                const jsonResponse = await response.json()
                console.log(jsonResponse)
                dispatch(addData(jsonResponse))
                console.log(fetchReddit)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <CardContainer />
        </>
    )
}
```

I suspect this is because the code doesn't contain any thunks. I'd also ideally just have a function within my Redux store I could call to fetch this data and automatically call the addData action so it'd update the state without having this code in my frontend.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I should refactor my code? What am I doing wrong?

Any points would be appreciated!

Comment: Where do you have your `mapDispatchToProps` fn? Or the `useDispatch` hook, whatever you are using.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to put that code in. I've added it now.

Comment: So the only way you've checked that the data is not filled is by using the selector? Have you checked that the action successfully passes the payload to the reducer?

Comment: No I haven't - what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: The easiest would be to just `console.log` inside the body of your action (removing the implicit return) and then in the reducer. If your action goes through, then everything is fine - it's just the selector which doesn't get the updated value that quickly.